# Passing Parameters to Base Class Constructors C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I like to keep my class declarations and definitions separate in C++. So, in a header I may define a 'base' class as follows:

```
# Base.h
class Base 
{
    int n;    
public:
    Base(int x);
};
```

and define its constructor implementation in a cpp file, i.e.,

```
# Base.c
Base::Base(int x) 
{
    n = x;
}
```

Now, if I define a 'derived' class that inherits the 'base' class, I can pass parameters to the base class as follows:

```
#Derived.h
class Derived : public Base
{
    int t;
public:
    Derived(int y) : Base(t) {t = y;}
}
```

But doing it this way requires that I place the body of the constructor for the Derived class in the header file, i.e., `{t = y;}`, and thus the constructor definition is no longer separate from its declaration. Is there a way to pass arguments to a class's base class constructor that still enables me to define the constructor for the derived class in a cpp file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes there is**, in the header file:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    int t;
public:
    Derived(int y); // Declaration of constructor
};
```

while in the cpp file:

```
Derived::Derived(int y) : Base(t) { // Definition of constructor
    t = y;
}
```

[Member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) are allowed in the definition of a class constructor as well as in inline in-class definitions. In case you're interested, I also recommend to take a look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for two small caveats regarding the order of initialization and the fact that members will be initialized before the compound constructor body is executed.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to pass arguments to a class's base class constructor that still enables me to define the constructor for the derived class in a cpp file?

Of course there is. The header can just declare the constructor, exactly as you did for `Base`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    int t;
public:
    Derived(int y);
};
```

then you can implement that in a source file, exactly as you did for `Base`:

```
Derived::Derived(int y) : Base(y), t(y) {}
```

Note that you'll have to pass the argument `y`, not the (as yet uninitialised) member `t` to the base constructor. Base sub-objects are always initialised before members.